# How to change Jetpack compose navigation component backstack behaviour?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I implemented the login, sign-up with jetpack compose on an app. I redirected the logged-in users to the main screen and keep the new user on to the login screen. But the problem is when I redirect the user from the login screen to the main screen and the user press the back button the login screen appears. Now I know it's a normal behavior of the navigation component but I need to change it. How can I do that?

Used this line for navigating to the main screen from the login screen

`navController().navigate("main_screen")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove last item from the back stack before navigating to the main screen using `popBackStack`:

```
navController.popBackStack()
navController.navigate("main_screen")
```

Comment: it freezes the next screen

Comment: @Tanjimahmed It's working totally fine to me. Most probably it's not related to navigation, check out if your app screen freezes with `main_screen` as initial destination.

Comment: yeah, my start destination is main_screen so what should I do now?

Comment: @Tanjimahmed and it still freeze? Try to comment out different parts of your view to find out which one causes freezing. If this didn't help, you can create a new question with the details of your freezing view.

Comment: I fixed it. it was a problem with jetpack compose recomposition